# Is a hosted button the safest option for accepting PayPal donations?

Tags: security, paypal, donations

I want to make a charity website and the only option will be to process payments using PayPal. I'm trying to make it so that the user can have an input field on my website where they decide how much to donate, but I'm suspicious as to whether that will open up many security vulnerabilities such as someone tampering with the amount entered by the user. Having a hosted button, you can't ask the user on your website for the amount they want to give, they enter it on PayPals payment form.

So would it be safer to let the user enter the amount they wish to donate in the payment form that comes up when the user clicks the donate button? If I wanted to make sure there was no tampering with variables such as 'business' and 'amount' in the PayPal form, how could I ensure such security for my website?

Is it possible to change the forms 'action' value to point to a function where I can filter the variables and do checks and then send the values to PayPal (I'm using PHP/CodeIgniter)?

Answer (score 0):

From a PayPal payment standpoint, there is no problem using an unsecured `<form>` element for a donation button.
Yes, that means a client can modify the `amount` and `business` of the form, but that doesn't matter, considering you want them to be able to modify the amount anyway.
And if someone changes the `business`; that only applies to *their* donation. So there is no problem there either.

The only thing you *do* want to secure is your backend / source files to prevent someone from **permanently** altering the `business` to point to a different account.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What kind of vulnerabilities would allow someone to permenantly change the business value? I'm going to use the hosted button for now to avoid any holes. Is it safe by itself (not adding any other kind of checking because all the variables are held with paypal)? Also, would adding https to the donate page help protect the backend?

Comment: Re. HTTPS; no, that would only affect the transfer of data, but not the security of the data in itself. If someone has control over your backend / whatever means are used to generate the rendered site's content, a hosted button will not suffice. They can simply replace the entire <form> element with one of their own.

Comment: So in summary; as far as securing the PayPal transactions goes, either a non-hosted or hosted button is fine and doesn't make a difference. You should spend most of your attention at securing your backend / whatever controls the content of your site. OWASP's top 10 webapp vulnerabilities is a good start; https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10 - ensure you have adequate protection against each of these attacks.

Comment: Thanks, I feel a bit at ease knowing that the PayPal form is safe. I ran a simulation using PayPals sandbox and things were okay. I'm not using a database or any other forms at all (except a form for emailing), and I only read in image file names in jQuery using a json file. Plus I have a plugin for a carousel and thats about it. CodeIgniter takes care of XSS filtering globally, and I don't set sessions or cookies (but PayPals form does?). Its just a really simple charity website and I wana make sure I don't mess it up.